# StackExchange.Redis - events from last N minutes

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am quite struggling with task to keep track about user interactions with articles for past N minutes.
Client that I have to use to access Redis instance is **StackExchange.Redis**.

Example:

- User likes *Article#111*.
  When API makes request, I have to know exact number of times Article#111 was liked for the past N minutes.
  For now, let's say that N=10.

Any guidance in solving this is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sorted set for that.

you can add to a key like `article:<id>:<interactionType>` (interactionType if you have multiple interactions) and value is `<userId>`

in order to get the no. of times article 1 was like in the past N minutes, you can do

`ZCOUNT article:1:likes <last-N-minutes-linux-timestamp> <current-time-stamp>`